# Every other MIDI note doesn't transmit?

Tags: midi

I'm using KMidimon to debug why my midi drums randomly stopped working.

It appears that every other midi note isn't being transferred.

I highly, highly doubt this is an issue with the drums because they're still triggering samples not on the computer.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could solve this?

EDIT: I've seen come to learn that these drums transmit the midi-on and midi-off notes one right after the other.  There is no sustain.  I still don't know why the result is what it is though.  And am interested in any debugging advice.